# Regex returns entire string iOS NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I cant seem to get this working. Im following apple documentation.

I have a sample string like such:

```
NSString * testString = @"Server Error -4";
```

I have a regex as follows:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Server\\sError\\s(-?\\d+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

When i do:

```
[testString substringWithRange:[regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:testString options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, testString.length)]];
```

I get the entire string back. (I.e the range match is from 0 to the end of the string). Any idea whats wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your expression - it just happens that the first match covers the entire string.

It looks from the structure of your expression that what you wanted to do is extracting the first *capturing group* of the match:

```
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:testString
               options:0
                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])];
NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *errorCode = [testString substringWithRange:matchRange];
```

Comment: actually [regex numberOfMatchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])] only returns 1. Meaning there is only 1 match.

Comment: @RafaelGutierrez Right, and that's the match that covers the whole string. Did you try the code from the answer?

Comment: @RafaelGutierrez You are welcome! If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer so that other site visitors know that your problem is solved.